# three20: Change text shadow of a TTButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

In my project, I use the Facebook API "three20": https://github.com/facebook/three20/

I use a TTButton in my UINavigationBar.
Is it possible to change the shadow of the text?

All buttons and labels in the UINavigationBar need an shadow OVER the
text. The text shadow of the TTButton is UNDER the text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried customizing your TTButtons with a TTStyle? TTTextStyle, which is a subclass of TTStyle can be used to customize the look of your text and its shadows, like the textcolor, shadow offset, and more.

example, in my subclassed TTDefaultStyleSheet class called, BNDefaultStyleSheet, i have this method:

```
- (TTStyle*)titleText {
 return [TTTextStyle styleWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] color:[UIColor orangeColor] next:nil];}
```

it returns the styling for a view component to which the styling may apply.

this doc here is the class reference for TTStyle and its subclasses which may come in handy
http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_style.php[1](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_style.php)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll try it the next days (my question is a half year old) and will give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only answer is: do not use three20, never.

Comment: It is so bad that the main developer can't support it any more and create a new project instead, it is called Nimbus. http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/ I'm so sorry that some of my projects are "infected" by Three20. It is VERY hard to maintain them, just impossible to improve. Google a bit about it, you'll find a lot of similar feedback. I'm pretty sure Nimbus is the same: the same main developer.

Comment: That's very interesting, I'll have a look on Nimbus! Thanks!

Comment: Three20 has grown beyond any reasonable maintainable capacity, this is true. Nimbus is a completely separate project from Three20 and aims to provide solid documentation with a similar feature set over time. @Slava: I'm curious whether you think Nimbus is the same as Three20 in a bad way or whether you simply mean similar in capacity?